# Can I Sort/Filter Cards in Trello by Label?

Tags: trello, trello-labels

I would like to use labels to help prioritize cards in Trello (e.g., "High", "Medium", "Low"). Is it possible to filter the cards displayed by Label (e.g., only showing the cards with the "High" label)?

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on the board title

2. Click on "more"

[image]

3. Click on "Search and Filter Cards"

[image]

4. Click on the labels or other attributes you wish to filter by.

[image]

[video screencast](http://screencast.com/t/g4ilTkuhMe8F)

Comment: Thank you! Any way to do the same thing on the iPhone app?

Comment: Not at the moment, but it's something we'd like to add in the future.

Comment: would be great to filter cards from all boards, for example getting all cards of a single organization

Answer (score 3):

Faster way: While on the trello screen, press "F" and then click the label, or start typing the name of the label you want to filter by.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Show Menu
2. Click on Search Cards
3. Type Label < name_of_label > in search box and press enter
4. Click on label that shows up to filter the board by this label
5. the board now indicates X search result in white text in a green background
   [image]
6. Click the X on the green background to remove the filter